# How does the decision of a feature is a feature of our object?

Tags: opencv, adaboost

Can anybody explain how does OpenCV make a decision about a feature of an object, when doing train_cascade???

Answer (score 2):

This is in the [train_cascade documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html)

> opencv_traincascade supports both Haar [Viola2001] and LBP [Liao2007] (Local Binary Patterns) features.

If you don't know what those features are, you can read the papers listed at the bottom of the documentation page or, to get a basic idea, Wikipedia: [Haar-like features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar-like_features), [Local binary patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns)

You select which feature is used using the `-featureType<{HAAR(default), LBP}>` option to the `opencv_traincascade` command.

Or perhaps you are asking about how the actual feature selection occurs. OpenCV uses variants of [AdaBoost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost). Here is a useful [presentation on AdaBoost](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~sochmj1/adaboost_talk.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the response, sir.
I've download the presentation.
Now i have some understanding about the boosting process that occur inside the feature pool for every stage of cascaded classifier. 
What i haven't understand is, how does OpenCV extract the haar feature from the positive samples?
as far i read the source code of opencv_traincascade, i don't find something like haar calculation/integral image. Maybe i missed something. 
And 2nd question, where's the ml.cpp placed? i can find ml.hpp, but not the ml.cpp. 
Thanks.